# Add data into a column in r by location in two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of sites and dates:

```
dat<-data.frame(Site = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),each = 5),
              Date = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),5))
```

I use a for loop to download flow data based on the site and date. Before the next iteration of the loop, I want to append the flow data for the site-date entries to this dataframe. I can do this like so:

```
# example flow data

q1<-data.frame(Site = rep(c('a'),5),
              Date = c(1,2,3,4,5),
              dailyQ = c(NA, 70, 65, NA, 41))

# left join to add flow data

library(dplyr)

dat<-left_join(dat,q1,by = c("Site" = "Site", "Date" = "Date"))
```

However in the next iteration, this method creates a new column for dailyQ:

```
# next loop iteration flow dataframe 

q2<-data.frame(Site = rep(c('b'),5),
               Date = c(1,2,3,4,5),
               dailyQ = c(43, 55, NA, NA, 72))

# appending next flow data into existing dataframe

dat<-left_join(dat,q2,by = c("Site" = "Site", "Date" = "Date"))

# >names(dat)

# [1] "Site"     "Date"     "dailyQ.x" "dailyQ.y"
```

What I want is to append these new entries into the same column on every iteration. I looked at the documentation for `*_join` and for stackoverflow questions but could not find a solution. I know I could do this with a nested `for` loop but I am looking for a more elegant solution. Maybe the solution lies in a different approach, any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  left_join(q1) %>%
  rows_update(q2, by = c("Site", "Date"))
```

The `left_join` step adds a `dailyQ` variable. `rows_update` will update matching rows without adding new variables, somewhat equivalent to:

```
dat %>%
  left_join(q1) %>%
  left_join(q2, by = c("Site", "Date")) %>%
  transmute(Site, Date, dailyQ = coalesce(dailyQ.y, dailyQ.x))
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know ```rows_update``` existed